# How to call action on submit (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, action

What is better way to do this: when user enters data in the form and submits form data is sending to some site. It is made in user edit page.

I need to call another action when user submits form.

Should I use before_edit filter or call it somehow in submit tag?

For example:

```
 def do
 //perform some sending actions
 end
```

In my view:

```
    <div class="submit" >
  <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn wide",  controller_do_path%></div>
```